# Trouble configuring xorg to disable touchpad

Tags: touchpad, gedit, synaptics, xorg.conf

I'm trying to follow the solution in [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316240) to disable extra touchpad device so that  syndaemon will work to disable the touchpad while typing so I won't keep having a jumping cursor (very hard to type right now)!

Having trouble following the instructions, not familiar with Ubuntu that much. I enter the following:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
```

That opens the text file.  I then paste the following:

```
# Disable generic Synaptics device, as we're using
# "DLL0704:01 06CB:76AE Touchpad"
# Having multiple touchpad devices running confuses syndaemon
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Then click <kbd>save</kbd> and get the following errors:

```
** (gedit:6473): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:6473): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:6473): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

So not able to fully complete this solution.  Let me know if you can help so I can perhaps make this new Dell Inspiron 15 7579 usable (trying both 17.04 on thumb drive and 16.04 LTS on external hard drive).

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the exact same problem. The protocol seems specific to Dell and provides a means to disable the Synaptics driver. So far it is working for me.

[Dell Support: Erratic cursor movement on the XPS 13/15 series laptops and Precision Mobile Workstations with Ubuntu 16.04 installed](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/4/SLN304721/erratic-cursor-movement-on-the-xps-9360-with-ubuntu-1604-installed)

> 1. Open a terminal and run in this command:
>
>    ```
>     sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/xps13-9360.conf
>    ```
>
>    (replace "xps13-9360" with the particulars of your own Dell laptop, i.e. "Inspiron15-7579")
> 2. Type `blacklist psmouse` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
> 3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save.
> 4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to verify the changes made to the file name.
> 5. You should now be back to the terminal. Type the command `sudo update-initramfs –u && sudo reboot` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>