# How do I Permanently Disable one of two Trackpad Drivers that run simultaneously

Tags: 18.04, xorg, touchpad, dell, synaptics

A link to [this Dell article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en) describes issues with Ubuntu *Bionic Beaver* and certain Dell Precision / XPS trackpads. I have a Dell Inspiron that is experiencing the same issue. The issue is that Ubuntu 18.04 runs two trackpad drivers at once on these Dell laptops, causing the cursor to jump around the screen.

If I issue the `xinput list` command I receive the following output:

```
Virtual core pointer 
  Virtual core XTEST pointer
  Synaptics TM3096-006
  SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad
```

To me that says I've got two mouse drivers running; `Synaptics TM3096-006` and `SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad`. The article I linked to above describes how to permanently disable the `SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad` driver by editing the `*synaptics-quirks.conf` and `*synaptics.conf` files.

My problem is that the `*synaptics-quirks.conf` and `*synaptics.conf` files don't even exist in my `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory. The files I have in this directory include:

```
10-amdgpu.conf
10-quirks.conf
10-radeon.conf
40-libinput.conf
70-wacom.conf
```

Do I simply create these `*synaptics-quirks.conf` and `*synaptics.conf` files in my `*xorg.conf.d/` directory? Or edit one (multiple) files already in the directory? The gist of the edit includes adding lines such as:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
MatchOS "Linux"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Comment: Wow, this has been a really annoying problem for me for years on my Dell XPS 13 (2015) on 14.04 which came installed. I needed to reboot every few hours to have a stable cursor. I duckducked and googled many many times and could never find a solution. The first step of your Dell link seems to have done it for me! Thank you so much! I wonder if I should perform the other steps...

Comment: The Dell article didn't solve it for me, but this did `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble configuring xorg to disable touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908069/trouble-configuring-xorg-to-disable-touchpad)